# Laravel5: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I've clone a repository from github,but getting error in routing for admin, the same code is running well on another developer machine, we both are using Window 8.

We are using `Auth` Middleware to validate user for logged in but when I tried to access the admin `http://example.com/admin` I am getting this error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

But frontend works fine. I've tried to execute following command in terminal but same issue after that

```
composer install
php artisan clear--compiled
```

Also I checked the registered routs & its showing in terminal by using command

```
php artisan route:list
```

[image]

Here are my route.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


// Logging in and out
get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin','prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth',], function () {

    resource('/', 'AdminController');

    resource('/countries', 'CountryController');

});
```

.htaccess file code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue, In my case the issue with .htaccess file, I've changed the baseurl in .htaccess file & it starts working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i just restarted apache and it worked i am on windows.